# SSRS 2008r2 installation integrated with Sharepoint

Tags: sql-server, reporting-services, sql-server-2008-r2

I would like to install SQL Server Reporting Services 2008r2 integrated with Sharepoint. When I am installing it there is a radio box which indicates installation mode. When I choose it for integrated mode then setup gives me an error. It says that I have to try  install with another SQL version except SQL advanced. But which SQL version should I install?

The Error message is **"Reporting Services in SharePoint integrated mode is not supported for EXPRESS_ADVANCED edition"**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is occurring as you're trying to install against SQL Server Express - from MSDN:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc281020(v=sql.105).aspx

Unsupported Features:

`SharePoint integrated mode is not supported`

You'll need to use a non-Express edition, i.e. Standard, Enterprise, etc.

Comment: Do I need enterprise version of SQL for integrating reports into the SharePoint? Can't I do that by a express version of SQL ?

Comment: No, as above it's not supported by SQL Server Express - please see the link for unsupported features of Reporting Services on SQL Server Express. Any non-Express version will support this - Enterprise is not specifically required. Standard, Enterprise and Datacenter are the standard commercial Editions, but Standard will be sufficient.

Comment: I have prepared a few reports by using BID SQL2008r2, now I want to deploy them into the SharePoint. But my SQL SErver is not a enterprise version. Concerning this may I deploy them without it or I must get an enterprise edition of SQL ?

Comment: Could you explain me briefly that how I am going to deploy these reports into the SharePoint 2007? I have searched to many sources from Internet but I didn't success :(

Comment: That's really out of scope for your question here, which I feel I've answered above. As far as commercial Editions go, you'll need at least Standard Edition for SharePoint Integrated mode. You can also develop and test against Developer Edition if it's available. Please accept the answer if it answers your initial question. Once you've addressed this issue, please log a new question with the full details of what you've tried and the specific errors you're getting if you still experience issues.